# Gradle copy file from resources to assets on compilation

Tags: android, gradle, copy-paste

I am looking for a way to copy src/main/res/values/* to /src/main/assets/www/xml/

I would like this to happen on compile, so I've been trying to get gradle to do such a thing, but with no success.

I appreciate any help with this :)

I have added my current gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "name"
        minSdkVersion 1
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 123
        versionName "123"
    }
}

dependencies {
    A huge bunch
}
```

Based on the copy task given from Enrico I made this work:

```
task myCopy(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/main/res/values'
    into 'src/main/assets/www/xml'
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    prepareDebugDependencies.dependsOn myCopy
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a copy task and make it a dependency of the compile task

```
task myCopy(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/main/res/values'
    into 'src/main/assets/www/xml'
}
assemble.dependsOn myCopy
```

EDIT: I assumed you had a compile task. Use assemble instead

Comment: The compilation task for Android projects (I'm not sure about other types of projects) is actually called `assemble`. I just tested it using assemble instead and it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for the copy task.
The compile.dependsOn myCopy gave an error, but i made the task work in another way :)

Comment: You are correct, assemble doesn't give any error. but on the other hand using assemble doesn't seem to do anything. I've accepted your answer and given the solution I ended up doing in my post.

Comment: Depending on `assemble` may not work for your particular project, but it does work and it's what you asked.

Comment: No, this doesn't copy anything prior to assemble task.